# Elements of the Quotient Group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have $G=\{m+n\sqrt3 : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $H=\{4m+2n\sqrt3 : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

I can see that H is a subgroup of G and H is a normal subgroup since G is abelian.  The issue I am having is writing out the quotient group: $G/H$.  I know that the order of $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$, but I am unsure as to how this helps, it seems as if it would be infinite.

Is this a correct assumption or am I looking at the quotient group incorrectly?

Comment: The argument with orders only applies when $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of $(G,+)$, $m$ can have one of the following forms
$$4m, 4m+1, 4m+2, 4m+3$$
and similarly $n$ can have one of the following forms
$$2n, 2n+1$$
Therefore $$G/H\subseteq\{H,1+H,2+H,3+H,\sqrt3 + H,1+\sqrt3+H,2+\sqrt3+H,3+\sqrt3+H\}$$
(Missed $3$ elements on first attempt as Mark points below :-) )

Comment: Your're missing many elements such as $1+\sqrt{3}+H$, $2+\sqrt{3}+H$, $3+\sqrt{3}+H$.

Comment: Just a follow up question, how would the order of each element be found? By using $ (g_1H)(g_2H)=(g_1g_2)H$ ?

Comment: @ElSpiffy Eg. $(1+H)+(1+H)+ (1+H)+(1+H)=4+H=H$, $(1+\sqrt 3+ H)+(1+\sqrt 3+ H)+(1+\sqrt 3+ H)+(1+\sqrt 3+ H)=4+4\sqrt 3 +H=H$. Orders corresponding to the set in the post are $$1,4,2,4,2,4,2,4$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove that

$$G/H=\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}+\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\sqrt{3}$$

So it has $8$ elements.

One has $G\simeq \Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}$ and $H\simeq 4\Bbb{Z}\times 2\Bbb{Z}$ and therefore

$$G/H\simeq \left(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}\right)/\left(4\Bbb{Z}\times 2\Bbb{Z}\right)\simeq \Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$$

All isomorphisms are additive group isomorphisms and trivially we have:

$$\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\simeq \Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}+\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Is my answer incorrect? My set is a group but if I'm wrong what elements am I missing?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife after looking at your post, I believe your answer was on the right track, all it was missing was elements: $(1+ \sqrt3 )+H,(2+ \sqrt3)+H, (3+ \sqrt3)+H$

Answer (score 0):

I will write cosets as of the form a+H.  Well since $4+2\sqrt{3}$$\in H$, $4+2\sqrt{3} + H$=$0+H$ so $2\sqrt{3}+H=-4+H$
Hence, we can replace any $b\sqrt{3}+H$ in G/H by a $-4+H$ if b is even so since we can replace any even integer times $\sqrt 3$ by some integer, the co-efficient of $\sqrt 3$ is always 1 or 0 in G/H.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to see this, visually, is to associate $G$ with the lattice of points on the $xy$-plane with integer coordinates. Then the subgroup $H$ is a sub-lattice.

The quotient operation corresponds to identifying all the points in the sublattice, by rolling the plane up into a torus whose surface is covered in a one-to-one fashion by the rectangle $[0,4)\times [0,2)$. The number of lattice points in that open-on-two-edges rectangle is the index you seek. Those lattice points are: $(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1)$ and $(3,1)$.